# PIng becomes unstable and higher than the previous one after my old router got replaced with new one

Tags: networking, wireless-networking, router, ping, wifi-configuration

My [ping](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nB9aX.png) become unstable as the title says, and I dont know what to do, I changed the [dns](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F5g0.png) already to cloudfare, disable the [power saving mode](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5FDtt.png), configure the [transmit power](https://i.stack.imgur.com/x7AGO.png) to highest and enable [throughput booster](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Rkvm8.png), I even tweak some registries with TCPOptimizer ([config 1](https://i.stack.imgur.com/NA3P7.png), [config 2](https://i.stack.imgur.com/kLVeQ.png)). It stills the same, the ping spikes, and higher than the previous, in my game before the replacement, I got 40 very stable ping, but now, it is around 50-60 and spike to 100+. How do I fix it, thanks

Comment: You can try a firmware update, but if that doesn't fix it, then either there's a malfunction with the router, or there is a structural problem with it. I have had this in the past after I got a modem upgrade from my ISP. After I contacted them and showed the ping results, they started an investigation and turned out, it was indeed a known issue with the firmware of that modem. There was no known fix, so they replaced my modem with a different one, and that resolved the issue.